# Menu mobile não fecha quando clica

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap-3

Galera gostaria de saber se é possíel fechar o menu mobile quando clicar o link pois quando expando o menu ele abre normalmente depois que clico no link ele vai para ancora que criei porem o menu continua aberto cobrindo o conteúdo no site
OBS: o site e onepage

Segue meu o código para fechamento do menu após o click
html:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                {{--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo-menu.png') }}" class="img-responsive logo" alt="jetwash"></a>--}}
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="list"><a href="#home" class="scroll link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="list"><a href="#about" class="scroll link">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li class="list"><a href="#services" class="scroll link">Serviços</a></li>
                    <li class="list"><a href="#franchise" class="scroll link">Franquia</a></li>
                    <li class="list"><a href="#midia" class="scroll link">Mídia</a></li>
                    <li class="list"><a href="#contact" class="scroll link">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav .link').click(function() {
        $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

criei esse código jquery para fazer o menu fechar porem não funciona porque

Comment: Já tentou usar slideUP e slideDown?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav .link').click(function() {
        $('.nav-collapse').slideUp();
    });
});

Comment: nossa cara vlw se uder responder a pergunta eu já marco como resposta obrigado

Comment: Por nada Kirito! Já inseri a resposta, valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slideUp e slideDown:

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.nav .link').click(function() {
   $('.nav-collapse').slideUp(); 
  });
 });